# NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting the above error, but I believe that I using rails 5:

```
turlingdrome$ rails -v
/Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/brianp/work in PATH, mode 040777
Rails 5.2.0

turlingdrome$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord
/Users/brianp/work/online-reporting/app/models/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brianp/work/online-reporting/config/routes.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/brianp/work/online-reporting/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/brianp/work/online-reporting/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't think that the --trace is useful... but can attach it if desired...

Comment: Looks like you are using rails 5.2. It doesn't get the Module ApplicationRecord which leads me to believe you need to bundle install.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options, you either change `app/models/client.rb` class declaration to:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Or alternatively you can create a `app/models/application_record.rb` file with the contents:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Comment: I switched from MongoDB to ActiveRecord and forgot about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Prior to version 5 Rails generated models that inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

```
# rails g model foo.
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Rails 5 introduced `ApplicationRecord` which is the model equivalent to `ApplicationController`. So on Rails 5 the following is generated:

```
# rails g model foo.
class Foo < ApplicationRecord

end
```

The ApplicationRecord class itself is generated when you run `rails new`.

However there is nothing magical about it - its just a superclass thats engrained in the conventions.

```
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

If you are getting `NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord` you either upgraded to Rails 5 without creating it or deleted it by mistake. The solution is simply to create the file.